# How to get the Ruby Regexp punctuation list from the `[[:punct:]]`?

Tags: regex, ruby

I'm using the `devise-security` gem and I setup it in order to require a `symbol` in the password (through `config.password_complexity`).

Now I want to show the possible symbols to be used.

Looking around in the gem's code, I found out that [they're actually using the Regexp `[[:punct:]]`](https://github.com/devise-security/devise-security/blob/5f06e98907aa93a2ebd190a82725b261bdf7f091/lib/devise-security/validators/password_complexity_validator.rb#L15).

Can you please tell me how to get the list of symbols out of the `[[:punct:]]` POSIX bracket expressions from the Ruby code?

I'm expecting to get a string like `#$%^*)`.

Comment: Take a look at Onigmo's [enc-unicode.rb](https://github.com/k-takata/Onigmo/blob/master/tool/enc-unicode.rb): _"Creates the data structures needed by Oniguruma to map Unicode codepoints to property names and POSIX character classes"_

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`[[:punct:]]` refers to what is considered punctuation in unicode. For example: https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/category/Po/list.htm

```
s = "foo\u1368bar" # => "foo፨bar"
s.split(/[[:punct:]]/) # => ["foo", "bar"]
```

> Sorry but my question is about to get that list using Ruby.

For the lack of a better idea, you can always loop from 1 to whatever is the maximum character number in unicode now, treat that as a character code, generate one-char string and match it against `[[:punct:]]` regex. Here's the quick and dirty implementation

```
punct = 1.upto(65535).map do |x|
  x.chr(Encoding::UTF_8)
rescue RangeError
  nil
end.reject(&:nil?).select do |s|
  s =~ /[[:punct:]]/
end
```

Result (as displayed by my macos):

[image: unicode punctuation]

Comment: Thank you, that I know it, but how to get all the symbols that matches the `[[:punct:]]` POSIX bracket expressions?

Comment: @ZedTuX: did you open the page? It has the list. If all else fails, you can always copy/paste character codes into an array.

Comment: Sorry but my question is about to get that list using Ruby.

Comment: I want to show the list of matching symbols available the user can use (apparently it depends on the machine's unicode).

Comment: @ZedTuX: or another, totally wild idea: loop from 1 to whatever is the maximum character number in unicode now, treat that as a character code and generate one-char string and match it against `[[:punct:]]` regex.

Comment: Well that's kind of what I'm actually trying right now, so it probably confirm that the way to do it :). Thank you.

Comment: @ZedTuX given the number of punctuation characters, it might make more sense to show some common examples rather than all available symbols to the user.

Comment: `.upto(65535)`?! Are you writing from 1997?

Comment: Also, another option would be to parse Consortium’s official Unicode spec, as, for instance, _Elixir_ does :)

Comment: @AlekseiMatiushkin: well that already gives me range errors. But please, I accept edits :)

Comment: It would give you range errors even with `.upto(128)` :)

Comment: @AlekseiMatiushkin: actually no, it does not

Comment: o_O indeed. Ruby is smart. `1.upto(65535).detect { |x| !x.chr(Encoding::UTF_8) rescue true } #⇒ 55296` → `128.chr(Encoding::UTF_8) #⇒ "\u0080"`.

Comment: Nice answer. You could avoid dealing with the `nil`'s  by using `each_with_object` instead of `map`: `(2 << 15).times.with_object([]) do |n,a|; c = n.chr(Encoding::UTF_8); a << c if c.match?(/\p{Punct}/); rescue RangeError; end`.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want an example of punctuation (because the full list is rather unwieldy), I would pick an example that you like and then ensure it actually matches the pattern:

```
example_punctuation = '(*!@$#jfas,./'.gsub(/[^[:punct:]]/, '')
# "(*!@$#,./"
```